# crontab daemon sends spurious emails

Tags: linux, cron

My crontab contains the following entry

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/some_command &> /dev/null
```

In other words, run some_command every two minutes and discard the output so that cron will not send me an email of the output.

However, about one or two times a day, I will receive an email containing the output of /usr/local/bin/some_command -- as though the &> /dev/null had been left off of the crontab entry.

```
from: Cron Daemon <root@hostanme.edu>
to: jsp@hostname.edu
subject:  Cron <jsp@psy58> /usr/local/bin/some_command &> /dev/null
...
[some_command output]
```

What might cause this?

Again, the command is being called by crond several hundreds of times a day, but in only one or two instances does it email me the output.

The actual command being called is:

```
/usr/local/bin/proctempalert -i='sensors -f | mail -s "`hostname` is HOT" myemail@gmail.com' &> /dev/null
```

And I know that it is running correctly, (that is, I get an email when my cpu is running hot).

Comment: Check the `man 5 crontab` manual, especially the part where it explains what shell is actually used to run your commands, and then realise that `/bin/sh` generally doesn't grok `&>` (unless it's a link to `bash`)...

Comment: @twalberg /usr/local/bin/proctempalert always sends something to stderr.  If /bin/sh doesn't grok &>, then it seems like I would get emails every two minutes.  Nevertheless, it's a good suggestion.  I will put the commands in bash scripts to see if that fixes the problem.  (You'd think I would have remembered that cron uses /bin/sh instead of bash since /usr/bin/at annoyingly warns me of this fact every time I call it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have this setup (with the '&> /dev/null' at the end of your command) is sending the command's stdout to /dev/null, when prevents crond from emailing the command's output to you.  But, it is not affecting output from the command to stderr.  I suspect that every once in a while, your command is sending some sort of message to stderr, and this is what is coming through in the spurious emails that you are receiving.  To send both stdout output and stderr output to /dev/null, put the following at the end of your command:

> /dev/null 2>&1

So, the whole thing would look like this:
    /usr/local/bin/proctempalert -i='sensors -f | mail -s "`hostname` is HOT" myemail@gmail.com' > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: In `bash`, `&> /dev/null` is equivalent to `> /dev/null 2>&1`. The real issue is probably that `cron` entries are run with `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, unless the OP has a `SHELL=...` line that wasn't shown in the question...

Comment: this seems to have fixed it.  it's the right answer, but, as @twalberg points out, for the wrong reason.